# How to select a radial basis function?

Tags: interpolation, radial-basis, rbf-kernel

Currently I am investigating interpolation of 3D data with radial basis functions (RBF) and I am wondering that there are quite a few families of such [(see table1 here)](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~wendland/research/old/reconhtml/node2.html).

However, I cannot find any discussion for engineers about the intuitive choice of them.
The are basically these aspects which differ across the RBF families:

- truncated power function with polynomials [slide 21](http://amadeus.math.iit.edu/~fass/Notes590_Ch11Print.pdf)
- oscillatory RBF [slide 36](http://amadeus.math.iit.edu/~fass/Notes590_Ch11Print.pdf)
- Euclid's hat functions [slide 44](http://amadeus.math.iit.edu/~fass/Notes590_Ch11Print.pdf)
- Buhmanns RBF [slide 49](http://amadeus.math.iit.edu/~fass/Notes590_Ch11Print.pdf) Looks pretty much like a polynomial RBF from Wendland to me :(

So why do we need so many of them? 
In my work I have to choose one of them, but I cannot justify the choice. :( 
So if someone asks me for that, I just tell that "I had a good dice"...